# Find $\int\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x+6}dx$. Why my solution is different from book?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I'm learning single variable calculus right now. Right now trying to understand integration with partial fraction. I'm confused in a problem from sometime. I think I'm doing right but answer in my book is something else. 
Please have a look at the images. 
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

The Solution given in my Book [image: Image 3] 
I know there's is a difference in finding value of A and B. But in previous exercise I was applying the same method and was getting correct answer. Please help. thankyou in advance.

Comment: $$x^2 - 5x + 6 = \biggl(x - \frac{5}{2}\biggr)^2 - \frac{1}{4},$$ not $+\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thankyou Daniel Fischer. I'm still getting different answer after correcting it.

Comment: $x^2-5x+6 = (x-3)(x-2)$.  In this case $ax^2+bx+c=x^2-5x+6$ so $a=1$, $b=-5$, and $c=6$ and the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ is $(-5)^2 - 4\cdot1\cdot6$ $= 25-24=1>0$.  Since the discriminant is positive, you can factor the polynomial using real numbers, so you'll get logarithms rather than arctangents. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Still not getting the answer.

Comment: What method did you use after making Daniel's correction? If I were trying to evaluate $\int 1/(u^2-a)$ I would use partial fractions; did you do that again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get the answer of my question from where I was wrong. [image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we get $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-5x+6}=1+\frac{5x-5}{x^2-5x+6}$$
can you show this?
now we calculate the zeros of $x^2-5x+6$, these are:$$x_{1,2}=\frac{5}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{25}{4}-\frac{24}{4}}$$ thus we get $$x_1=3$$ or $$x_2=2$$
and we get $$x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)$$ and we can make the ansatz:
$$\frac{5x-5}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-3}$$
multiplying by the denominators we obtain:
$$\frac{5x-5}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{A(x-3]+B(x-2)}{x^2-5x+6}$$
and we get $$5x-5=x(A+B)-3A-2B$$
from here you will get $$5=A+B$$ and $$-5=-3A-2B$$ you must solve this system

Comment: i'm not ready with my threat

Comment: I am not totally convinced that this is an answer to the question, but it is no longer so bad as to warrant the downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, I see what you're doing.
$$\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{A\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-5x+6)+B}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{A(2x-5)+B}{x^2-5x+6}$$
Which sets up the system of equations
$$2A=1$$
$$-5A+B=-1$$
Another approach is just to perform algebraic manipulations. It may make the problem seem less procedural.

$$\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(2x-2)}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}(2x-5+5-2)}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{2x-5}{2(x^2-5x+6)}+\frac{3}{2(x^2-5x+6)}$$
In any event, you're still left with the same problem. While the first fraction can be integrated with the substitution $u=x^2-5x+6$, the second one still has a quadratic denominator that needs to be handled some how. Obvious methods include integration by parts, or inverse trigonometric substitution (circular will do, but hyperbolic is cleaner for the $x^2-1$ form).

Answer (score -1):

If your way is right, then the answer doesn't matter, because it is the representation of  the value, if you put the value and plot it on a garph, you will see you will get the same answer.